# Is this proof rigorous enough? Subspace of discrete space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> **Problem**: Every subspace of a discrete space is discrete.

**Proof1** :Let $X$ be a discrete space with the discrete topology $\tau = 2^X$ and $Y$ be subspace with its topology $$\tau_Y = \{ Y \cap U : U \in \tau \}$$

Then exactly two scenarios can happen:

$$Y \cap U =\left\{\begin{matrix}
\emptyset \\ 
Z
\end{matrix}\right.$$

where $Z \in 2^X$ and certainly $Z \in 2^Y$, so $Z \in 2^X \cap 2^Y = 2^Y$. But $Z$ was an arbitrary element from $2^X$, so this shows $Y \cap U \in 2^Y$

**Proof2**

Assume that $\tau_Y \neq 2^Y$, this would mean $Y \cap U \notin 2^Y \implies Y \cap U \in X - Y \implies Y \cap U = \emptyset$ so this topology only contains the empty set. But that is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs are rigorous enough despite being somewhat clumsy. Is it obvious to you that even the following suffices to see that the discrete topology on $X$ induces the discrete topology on $Y$?

$$Y\subset X \Rightarrow \{Y\cap U\}_{U\in2^X}=2^Y \square$$

The above implication is not exactly trivial yet for teaching that is rigorous enough.

Yet, in the sense of formal proofs, nor your proofs, neither mine are rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A \subset Y$ be arbitrary. Then $A \subset X$, so $A \in \tau$, so $A = Y \cap A \in \tau_Y$ ($A \subset Y$ iff $A \cap Y = A$...) and so $\tau_Y = 2^Y$. So $Y$ is discrete. No need for case distinctions at all.